# Big inline style in head (critical css) block text rendering

Tags: html, css, styles, block, inline

I cannot find any reason for this on the Internet.
If I put my critical css (quite big) on the head tag then it block text rendering on the body. But if I put my critical css right after body tag then the text can be rendered properly. Like this:

Text in the body not be rendered immediately

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>// My inline critical css (quite big) go here</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        // Some text here
        // Async styles
    </body>
</html>
```

Text in the body can be rendered immediately

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <style>// My inline critical css (quite big) go here</style>
        // *Some text here* could not be rendered immediately
        // Async styles
    </body>
</html>
```

Any limitations of big inline style in head?